# Add objects to list in loop in IL Emit - Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program

Tags: c#, reflection, cil

The following is my C# code:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
for(int Count = 0; Count < 5; Count++)
    list.Add(Count);
return list;
```

My corresponding emitted code is as follows:

```
LocalBuilder list = ILout.DeclareLocal(typeof(List<int>));
LocalBuilder Count = ILout.DeclareLocal(typeof(int));
LocalBuilder CmpRes = ILout.DeclareLocal(typeof(bool));
ConstructorInfo DictConstrctor = typeof(List<int>).GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
MethodInfo methodinfo_add = typeof(List<int>).GetMethod("Add", new[] { typeof(int) });
Label IL_001C = ILout.DefineLabel();
Label IL_000B = ILout.DefineLabel();

ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, DictConstrctor);
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0, list);
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1, Count);

ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, IL_001C);
ILout.MarkLabel(IL_000B);
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0, list);
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1, Count);
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Call, methodinfo_add);

ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1, Count);
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Add);

ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1, Count);
ILout.MarkLabel(IL_001C);
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1, Count);
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2);
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Clt);
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_3, CmpRes);
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_3, CmpRes);
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, IL_000B);

ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0, list);
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

It is throwing an exception - "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.".

What is it that I am doing wrong here?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That looks like it loops to 2... is that intentional?

Comment: If you want to play with emit, I strongly recommend the Sigil library (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sigil/) - it is **designed** to make this a lot more intuitive, with an API that makes it hard to fail, and giving clear error messages if you do still manage it.

Comment: Thanks! I will try agin later. Yes, count is 2. I was trying too many things, so I might have changed the count to 5..

Comment: I will note your comments, which are very useful. i am still a beginner in IL. callvirt and removing cmpres did the trick. I am still not convinced how commenting those two lines of code where i store and load "CmpRes" makes it an invalid program. Please see : I tried CmpRes both as int as well as bool.

Comment: I didn't say that the store/load made it invalid; I said that it doesn't serve any useful purpose

Comment: I am saying by commenting those two lines, the code worked. Any idea?

Comment: as I said: "local 3" ***does not exist***; thus `Stloc_3` and `Ldloc_3` are malformed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115949/discussion-between-badari-and-marc-gravell).

Comment: Additional note (in case you missed it in the answer) - you didn't actually initialize `Count` to `0`. As it happens, you'll get away with it due to a flag that is added by default (that wipes the stackframe upon entry), but it is good practice to be explicit

Comment: Alright! :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1, Count);
```

and

```
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1, Count);
```

make no sense. No additional parameter is needed if you are explicitly saying "use local 1"

Likewise:

```
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_3, CmpRes); 
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_3, CmpRes);
```

although frankly I'm not sure that `CmpRes` serves any useful purpose; no point storing and loading - just leave it on the stack

Note: if `Count` is "local 1", then `CmpRes` is "local 2"; there is no "local 3", so `Stloc_3` and `Ldloc_3` are malformed.

And again here:

```
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0, list);
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1, Count);
```

--

Next we get to the call; you're doing a static call:

```
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Call, methodinfo_add);
```

but that is an instance method on an object, so should be a virtual call.

and again another local fumble here:

```
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1, Count);
```

and here:

```
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1, Count);
```

and here:

```
ILout.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0, list);
```

However, I also have severe doubts that this loop (even if fixed) does what you expect it to do - if I read it right, it is actually:

```
var list = new List<int>();
for(int i [= 0] ; i < 2 ; i++) // note the 0 here implicit not explicit
{
    list.Add(i);
}
return list;
```

Comment: "but that is an **instance** method on an object, so should be a **virtual** call". Although it is clear that you know it, the sentence may mislead others. Instance method will not necessarily mean a virtual method... He need to use callvirt opcode because **any** instance method use it for the `this != null` check.

Comment: @DudiKeleti although more generally, it is simply the correct instruction for the scenario; all mainstream compilers will emit callvirt for object methods, even if they aren't virtual (let the JIT worry about the difference). There is a third category, "constrained call", for more complex scenarios (generics, interface methods on structs, etc). All fun.

Comment: yes sure. although if we are more specific, in this case for example, `new MyClass.Method()` the IL will looks like this: `call instance void Namespace.MyClass::Method()`. but enough to bother you ;)